# Xcode 4 always shows "Scanning for working copies", keeps re-downloading libs

Tags: xcode, cmake, xcode4.5

*note I have read several other questions on this but am still confused*

**Firstly:** I have a clean install of XCode 4.5 and have used it to open and build a CMake-generated .xcodeproj. Things build fine but as many other questions mention, it constantly shows a @Scanning for working copies" progress bar.

I have not distributed or packaged any apps or anything like that, and I have no SCM set up.

**Secondly:**
Every time I launch Xcode 4.5, it starts downloading:

- Xcode 4.5 Developer library
- OS X 10.8 Core Library
- iOS 6.0 Library

I've waited for it to finish a couple of times but still the next time, it does it again. It doesn't seem to stop me being able to build, what's going on here?

No idea if it's related, but I earlier got a warning from a snapshot saying I didn't have access to the location it wanted to save to (inside the XCode.app dir IIRC).

Comment: I have same problem.. everytime I launch xcode 4.5, it downloads these 3 library over and over again. any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually stop the downloading of these libraries from the preferences > downloads  .Also make sure the "Check for and install updates automatically" is unchecked.

Comment: None of these libs are (or ever were) listed in Downloads. All I saw were iOS simulator versions and command-line tools.

Comment: There are two tabs in under the Downloads. Did you check the Documentation tab? All libraries must be listed there.
check this [photo](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/42881080/Screen%20Shot%202012-09-25%20at%2011.03.24%20AM.png)

Comment: Hmm... I need to check when I get back on my Mac but this might be it!

Comment: OK it seems they were documentation, but _why_ they kept downloading I still don't know. The first problem is still happening.